# What are your experiences with NPanday?

Tags: .net, apache

Have you used [NPanday](http://npanday.codeplex.com/) to integrate Visual Studio with [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/)? If so, did it work well? Would you use it again?

Edit: Less specifically, I suppose, the problem I'm trying to solve is this:
I have a C# solution in Subversion that relies on other projects elsewhere in the Subversion tree. I'd like to build my project using Hudson. I can build the other project DLL locally, and reference it, but this doesn't work for the CI server. I can't reference the project because Hudson copies the project folders elsewhere, with a new name. What's the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While some of the problems still exist, NPanday has made quite some progress since 1.1 - it has moved to [Apache](http://incubator.apache.org/npanday/), and [1.4.0-incubating has been released](http://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/apache-npanday-1-4-0-incubating-released-net-for-maven/) a while ago.

**--Original answer: is quite outdated--**

We tried to use NPanday even also together with Hudson. It works, but in NPanday 1.1 the lifecycle is still quite java-like and not very adjusted to the needs for .NET projects.

The Plugin can maintain a pom.xml with all source-files. Support for resources is given, but not complete yet: localized satelite-assemblies are not supported.

The plugin also works for English VS installations only (patch in progress)

We ended up building our own maven-plugins which I'm now trying to get into NPanday for v1.2. (to be released before summer, hopefully)

In Teamcity you can easily depend on artifacts produced by other buildprojects, but Hudson does [not seem to support that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827515/sharing-build-artifacts-between-jobs-in-hudson).

Comment: I have now been comitter on the NPanday team since October 2011; stuff is getting better and better!

Answer (score 0):

Andrew,

I have been working on build and release management capability utilizing the NPanday and Continuum (maestro) . There are some hiccups but slowly its improving and provides benefits of CI and centralized binary management (main advantage).  I never tried hudson but suggest you to go ahead with NPanday and continuum(maestro) combination to achieve CI.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using npanday on mac os x and using mono for .Net

But the projects won't get compile or packaged

Not sure if still npanday is active or not

Comment: Community was a bit small for apache, but if more people where involved it was close to a 1.5 release  https://github.com/apache/npanday