# Jenkins Get a file from workspace using Java

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have a job on Jenkins that compile an *.exe files .

Using ["Copy To Slave Plugin"](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+To+Slave+Plugin), i manage to copy to job Workspace the files after compilation.
The URL is like that: job//ws/output/.
I want to use another job in a different slave that get this files and execute them there, this job is written in java (running with maven).

I couldn't find any Example of 'how to get file from jenkins master'.

There is anyone who knows how to Receive this files, or you have maybe other proposal how to inject the files directly from one slave to another (trigger by Jenkins of course).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you upload the exe file as an artifact to a repository (nexus, artifactory)? if so then you'll be able to get and execute them in the second job using maven.

Comment: another option is to use this plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Clone+Workspace+SCM+Plugin (credit to http://stackoverflow.com/a/2520797/947784)